.NET MAUI Border hides the content
I'm trying to use Borders instead of Frames because there are more opportunities and Borders are more flexible, but when I replace the Frames with borders the content inside is hidden or only white.
 <Border
         HeightRequest="80"
         Background="blue"
         Stroke="Red">
     <Border.Shadow>
         <Shadow Brush="Black"
                 Offset="10,10"
                 Opacity="0.8" />
     </Border.Shadow>
 <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,*" >
...
     <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                      Orientation="Horizontal"
                      Margin="15,15,0,0">
...
     </StackLayout>
 </Grid>
 </Border>

Does anyone experienced similar issue before? And what is best advice to be used in .NET MAUI?

Did you make sure no default styles in your Styles.XAML is messing with your border control

After whole day of trying everything, I saw that somehow my Border control was wrapped inside a Frame control on top level. That is the main reason for not showing the UI elements inside the Border. Don't do the same mistake and wrap Border inside a Frame


Good to see you've figured it out on your own. However, based on your code snippet you posted, Border is not wrapped inside a Frame, maybe next time you can provide a minimal and reproducible sample which will help reproduce the issue. 2. You can also check accept your own answer as it may help others facing the same issue!


You have no content with some height in the Border. The Grid has an auto height. Because the Stacklayout (Which you should replace to HorizontalStackLayout) has no content, it doesn't expand, so the Grid also.
If this is not working check your default style for border in Ressources > Styles > Styles.xaml
Allways try to add background colors for testing. With this technique you allways see which components are visible.
